# What is the most probable number of acceptable screens in the next batch of 10 screens and what is the probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A novel process of manufacturing laptop screens is under test. In recent tests, it is found that 75% of the screens are acceptable. What is the most probable number of acceptable screens in the next batch of 10 screens and what is the probability?

Does that mean 7 screens out of 10 will pass with a probability of 0.75?
I was skeptical about using binomial or geometric probability law because there is a huge difference in each calculation. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant binomial distribution:

[image]

If you're forced to choose an integer, then $n=8$, and $p = 0.2815684$.

Comment: Hi David thank you for the answer. 
Can you please explain how can i calculate that ?

Comment: Gosh... I think you have to do *some* of the work on your own!

Comment: Okay, is it Pr(N=10)= 10Cx (0.75)^x *(0.25)^(10-x)?

Comment: Nope.  After all, you have an undefined $x$ in your formula, and clearly the answer is a fixed real number.

Answer (score 0):

Tabulating (3/4)^x * (1/4)^(10-x) * (10 C x) for x<11, we get that 8 is the most likely number with probability about 28.2%.